# how to redirect_to url depand on the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have in my project users and providers.
User has one provider which means in order to be a provider you should sign in as a user first.
I have a navigation bar which has profile link which send the user to his profile view.
But if the user has a provider user, I want the link to redirect to the provider profile page and not to the user one.

Does someone has an idea?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways to realize that. 
First of all you can redirect_to provider_path() in your profile action if user have a provider.
Second way is to check if user.provider in your navigation bar, and then render that link you need (i prefer extract this logic to helper).